# Same ASP.NET web application, but different performance in windows and mac-os, unix or linux

Tags: asp.net, performance

I deploy a asp.net web application to datacenter in usa using windows 2008 64bits and sqlserver express 2008.

if i using mac-os or linux ubuntu or unix or mobile android or iphone or ipad my application works better ... very fast... but if i using windows xp, 7, 2008 this same application performance is bad .. more bad .... it's joke? I using power configuration in pc (4gb ram, dual core).

what's happen ?

Thanks
Douglas

Answer (score 0):

It probably has more to do with the differences between the browsers than anything else. Since you can't really use the exact same browser on all systems, try using a browser that allows you to see a time window of when resources are pulled down and how long they take. I know Chrome has built in tools for this, and I'm sure Firefox does as well.